# How to Sum by Column in Pandas DF and Remove Additional Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the form:

```py
    Sales House Station Day Date    Time    Daypart  Total          Unique Key
0   CARLTON     CARLTON Mon 3AUG20  1213    DAYTIME  0              CARLTON_ 3AUG20
1   CARLTON     CARLTON Mon 3AUG20  2307    POSTPEAK 30             CARLTON_ 3AUG20
2   CARLTON     CARLTON Tue 4AUG20  1015    COFFEE   30             NaN
3   CARLTON     CARLTON Tue 4AUG20  1027    COFFEE   30             CARLTON_ 4AUG20
4   CARLTON     CARLTON Wed 5AUG20  1310    DAYTIME  30             CARLTON_ 5AUG20
```

The `Unique Key` column is just a column I have added to try make this process easier (correct me if I am wrong please!). Essentially I would like to sum the `Total` column by using the `Unique Key` column, but also remove the extra rows associated with the `Unique Key` and only leaving one..

As an example, the above df would come out as the below. In this instance there is a match for row 1 and row 2, which the `Total` row should be summed, and then row 2 removed..

```py
    Sales House Station Day Date    Time    Daypart  Total          Unique Key
0   CARLTON     CARLTON Mon 3AUG20  1213    DAYTIME  30             CARLTON_ 3AUG20
1   CARLTON     CARLTON Tue 4AUG20  1015    COFFEE   30             NaN
2   CARLTON     CARLTON Tue 4AUG20  1027    COFFEE   30             CARLTON_ 4AUG20
3   CARLTON     CARLTON Wed 5AUG20  1310    DAYTIME  30             CARLTON_ 5AUG20
```

Is there a way to easily do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you need `df.groupby()` method.

I would try doing this in three steps:

```
aggregated = df.groupby(['Station', 'Date'])['Total'].sum().reset_index() # Getting sum
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Station', 'Date'])                              # Removing duplicated rows
df = df.drop('Total', axis=1).merge(aggregated, on=['Station', 'Date'])   # Merge back
```

**Edited** according to the comment (added `df = df.drop_duplicates(['Station', 'Date'])`) line in order to remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not removing the rows with the duplicate `Unique Keys`?

Comment: your code works, thanks. But does not remove the duplicates. I have used `df.drop_duplicates(subset='Unique Key', keep="first")` to do this. If you could update your answer to reflect this it will be a better rounded answer.

Comment: I've just edited the answer, thank you. You don't even need to create `Unique Key` column, you can pass list of columns to `.drop_duplicates()` method. Try it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227890/discussion-between-gleb-v-and-jezrael).

Comment: If you read question carefully, you can see here `The Unique Key column is just a column I have added to try make this process easier (correct me if I am wrong please!)`. So what I am doing here - is helping @Dean understand, that he don't need to create another column. And now trying to prove you that my answer is correct while you're downvoting my answers. Such a great deal for such a contributor. Thank you!

Comment: I miss it, so +1, sorry.